# How to exit a For loop for JavaTree object

Tags: for-loop, vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to loop through and find an item from javatree object and compare it with the one from my datatable, if the item is found and is the same as mine exit the loop but it does not exit it continues to loop. Please see the script im using below with the attached example.

```
Dim i,x, assignSkill
assignSkill = DataTable("SkillName", dtGlobalSheet)

For i = 0 To (JavaWindow("Admin Console [Admin]").JavaTree("Skill Container").GetROProperty("items count"))
    if JavaWindow("Admin Console [Admin]").JavaTree("Skill Container").GetItem(i) = assignSkill Then
        msgbox ("Skill found")
        Exit For
    Else
        msgbox ("Not found")
    End If
Next
```

[image]

Comment: Check the typenames and values of `assignSkill` and `JavaWindow("Admin Console [Admin]").JavaTree("Skill Container").GetItem(i)`. Check if values have trailing spaces.

Comment: I don't understand: your script does not find a match despite of it should do **or** does not exit the loop _notwithstanding_ that displays the `Skill found` message?

Comment: @Ansger Wiechers thank you for the response i will try to user your advice.

Comment: @JosefZ my loop do find the match but instead of it stopping it continue looping until it trows an error because there is no more items to match with, however I am still a novice  to vbscript automation

Comment: Thanks guys for helping, i found out that the string coming from the tree object had pe-apended string. That is why the item i was compering with was not found in the loop. I now truncated the unwanted string to get what im looking for. Thanks guys again for helping